# jQuery datepicker dateFormat filter causes datepicker icon to disappear

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jQuery ui v1.10.3 and attempting to force the datepicker to return dates in the format dd/mm/ccyy

With the code, below, I'm able to get the datepicker to do just that. However, the datepicker icon goes away. When I comment my code out, the datepicker icon is there alongside the input field as expected.

What am I missing?

html:

```
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="_todate" name="_todate" tabindex="1" runat="server" value="{//balance_info/driver/parms/parm[@name='datehi']/@value}" />
```

Script:

```
jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
```

Comment: The icon goes away, but if you click in the input field, does a calendar still appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's noted in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger).

```
jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```